# Problema al usar una funcion de JS que impacta en HTML en otro JS

Tags: javascript, html

Cómo va?

Estoy haciendo un proyecto personal y trataba de usar una función que hice para que impacte en el `html` mostrando una alerta, llamando a este método en el `html` o en el `JS` que importo a este `html` funciona. Pero cuando trato de usar ese método para mostrar la alerta en otro archivo `JS` me dice que algunos de esas variables que uso no están definidas.

Dejo el código que estoy usando:

**`html`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>alerta</title>
        <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>            
        <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
    function imprimir(){
        Swal.fire({
        html: `sda`,
        timer: 2000,
        imageUrl: 'a.gif',
        background: '#000000',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        onBeforeOpen: () => {


        },
        onClose: () => {

        }
        }).then((result) => {

    })
    }

    exports.module = { imprimir };
```

Si tienen alguna consulta sobre esto, avisen.

Answer (score 0):

No funcionará porque estás usando [CommonJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) en lugar de [ESModules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/).

CommonJS es una especificación para usar módulos que no es compatible con el navegador.

La variable **global** `exports` es solo expuesta en Node.js, no en el navegador y es un objeto literal. Esta especificación difiere mucho de ESModules porque están pensadas para problemas diferentes. CommonJS se pensó para backend, mientras que ESModules es agnóstico.

Para exportar un elemento desde un módulo se debe usar la palabra reservada `export`.

```
export function imprimir() {
  ...
}
```

En otro archivo (igualmente de tipo module) debes importarlo:

```
import { imprimir } from './script.js'

imprimir()
```

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por tu interes en ayudar. Intente eso y me da el siguiente error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module, debe ser porque uso el import en un archivo ejecutado en node.js, no?